# javascript - how to turn an element id into a defined variable

Tags: javascript

I have this code

```
var myObject = {
  prop1: [ 
    'this is prop1:',
    ['answer1', 'prop2'],
    ['answer2', 'prop3']
  ],

  prop2: [ 
    'this is prop2:',
    ['answer1', 'prop1'],
    ['answer2', 'prop3'], 
  ],

  prop3: [ 
    'this is prop3:',
    ['answer1', 'prop1'],
    ['answer2', 'prop2'],
  ]
};
```

Now let's say I make this variable

```
var myVar = myObject.prop1;
```

so suppose I want to `console.log(myVar);`

It will give me the array prop1 with all its values.

I would like to mutate the variable myVar and change it to:

```
myVar = myObject.prop2;
```

I want to do this using the string that are attached next to the answers
so basically answer1 to question1 has prop2 as a string.

I want to get that string and convert it as a the property prop2 to call it.

I tried:

```
var pullProp = myObject.prop1[1][1];  // which is the string prop2

myVar = myObject.pullProp;

console.log(myVar);  // i get undefined
```

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: use bracket notation: myVar = myObject[pullProp]; for dynamical calls of object properties

Comment: It worked!!! thanks sooooo much!!!!!! @sinisake

Answer (score 1):

You could use the content of

```
myObject.prop1[1][1] // 'prop2'
```

as key for

```
myVar = myObject[myObject.prop1[1][1]];
```

You may have a look for [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

> Property accessors provide access to an object's properties by using the dot notation or the bracket notation.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> object.property
> object["property"]
> ```

```js
var myObject = {
        prop1: ['this is prop1:', ['answer1', 'prop2'], ['answer2', 'prop3']],
        prop2: ['this is prop2:', ['answer1', 'prop1'], ['answer2', 'prop3']],
        prop3: ['this is prop3:', ['answer1', 'prop1'], ['answer2', 'prop2']]
    },
    myVar = myObject.prop1;

console.log(myVar);
myVar = myObject[myObject.prop1[1][1]];
console.log(myVar);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no property defined on myObject named `pullProp`. `pullProp` is a variable defined at the same scope level as myObject.

What I think you want to achieve is:

```
myVar = pullProp;
```

Comment: yeah but pullProp = myObject.prop1[1][1] so doesnt that mean that pullProp will be "prop2"?  so how do i get that string and convert it as a property?

Comment: You said: "I would like to mutate the variable myVar and change it to:
myVar = myObject.prop2;".

Comment: Add it as a property of what, the myVar object?

Comment: maybe I explained it wrong :( sorry but @sinisake answered it :)

Comment: Ok cool, glad you worked it out